# Show files from 3 directories in 3 columns and each files creation/modified date

Tags: php

I'm looking for some assistance with getting this working.

In the root I have an index.php file (shown below) and I also have 3 folders. Images get randomly added to these folders, what I want to do is within these 3 columns in a table is to show (sort) the latest files in each folder with their creation/modified date, or basically the date they were added.

I've added a screenshot to show what I have so far, the 3 columns are working fine by pulling through the latest files in each folder. However, under each image they seem to all have the same modified date, which is wrong.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$dirname = "dir1";
$dirnameTwo = "dir2";
$dirnameThree = "dir3";

$cam1 = scandir($dirname, 1);
$cam2 = scandir($dirnameTwo, 1);
$cam3 = scandir($dirnameThree, 1);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='10'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='max-age=0' />
    <meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='0' />
    <meta http-equiv='expires' content='Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT' />
    <meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />
</head>
<html>

<body>
<style type="text/css">
    .pi-title {
        padding: 1rem;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pi-title">
            <h3>Testing</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="table-container col-md-12">
            <table class="table" border='1' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' bordercolor='#ccc'>
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">1</th>
                    <th scope="col">2</th>
                    <th scope="col">3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr></tr>
                <tr>
                    <?php
                    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
                    array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', ($files = glob("*.*", GLOB_BRACE))), SORT_DESC, $files);
                    $dirs = array($dirname, $dirnameTwo, $dirnameThree);
                    foreach ($files as $filename) {
                                    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
                                    if (file_exists($filename)) {
                                        echo "</tr>";
                                        echo "<td><font face='Arial' size='6'>$i</font></td>";
                                    echo "<td><img src='$dirs[0]/$cam1[$i]' height='180' width='220'><br>" . date("F d Y H:i", filemtime($filename));
                                    echo "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><img src='$dirs[1]/$cam2[$i]' height='180' width='220'><br>" . date("F d Y H:i", filemtime($filename));
                                    echo "</td>";
                                    echo "<td><img src='$dirs[2]/$cam3[$i]' height='180' width='220'><br>" . date("F d Y H:i", filemtime($filename));
                                    echo "</td>";
                                    }
                           if ($i === 12) break;
                           }
                        if ($i === 12) break;
                    }
                    ?>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uujBn.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here I will do it for 1 of them:

```
//covers a single folder
$dirname = "dir1";
$cam1 = [];
foreach(array_diff(scandir($dirname), ['.','..']) as $file){
    $pathname = $dirname.DIRECORY_SEPERATOR.$file;
    if(is_dir($pathname)) continue; //skip folders

    $cam1[filemtime($pathname).'-'.$file] = $pathname;
}

ksort($cam1, SORT_NATURAL);
$latest = end($cam1);
```

Ideally you would use the above in a function or a loop. A loop or function is better because if you have to add another folder in, you just add it to the array or call the function with it. Without that (they way you have it) if you want to add another one, you have to duplicate all the code for it. For an array it would be like this:

```
//covers all 3 directories
$dirs = ["dir1","dir2","dir3"];

$results = [];
foreach($dirs as $dirname){
   $res = [];
   if(!is_dir($dirname)) continue; //or issue an error

   foreach(array_diff(scandir($dirname), ['.','..']) as $file){
       $pathname = $dirname.DIRECORY_SEPERATOR.$file;
       if(is_dir($pathname)) continue; //skip folders

       $res[filemtime($pathname).'-'.$file] = $pathname;
   }

   ksort($res, SORT_NATURAL);
   $results[$dirname] = end($res);
}

//['dir1' => 'dir1/somefile.jpg', 'dir2' => ....]
```

To explain it.

The `array_diff` removes paths like `.` or `..` which is a common annoyance with `scandir`. These are like the back or up folders.

We can check if a give "path" is a directory to skip those with continue just as an extra precaution.

[filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)

Get's the time of the file as a UNIX timestamp, then we append the filename because if 2 files were made at the exact same second we want to keep them both.

Then we can sort the keys, which should (if I remember right) put the highest one last (or the bigger most recent timestamp).  Then we just grab the last one from the array with `end`.

The `scandir` sort argument (argument 2) only works on the file names.

**UPDATE**

> [how] would I echo the timestamp

Well there are 2 easy ways, you can use `filemtime` again:

```
echo filemtime($results[$dirname]);
```

Or you could add it in when you loop over them:

```
   foreach(array_diff(scandir($dirname), ['.','..']) as $file){
       $pathname = $dirname.DIRECORY_SEPERATOR.$file;
       if(is_dir($pathname)) continue; //skip folders

       $filemtime = filemtime($pathname);

       //$res[filemtime($pathname).'-'.$file] = $pathname;
       //change the structure of this to:

       $res[$filemtime.'-'.$file] = [
             'pathname'=>$pathname,
             'mtime' => $filemtime
       ]; 
   }
```

And then you would do

```
echo $results[$dirname]['mtime'];
```

For the final one I will do it as a complete function (Preferred):

```
//all the above stuff wrapped in a function
function getLatestFromFolders($dirs, array $exclude = ['.','..']){
   //normalize to array
   if(!is_array($dirs)) $dirs = [$dirs];
   $results = [];
   foreach($dirs as $dirname){
      //if(!is_dir($dirname)) continue; //or issue an error
      if(!is_dir($dirname)) throw new Exception($dirname.' Not found');

      $res = [];

      foreach(array_diff(scandir($dirname), $exclude) as $file){
          $pathname = $dirname.DIRECORY_SEPERATOR.$file;
          if(is_dir($pathname)) continue; //skip folders

          $filemtime = filemtime($pathname);

          $res[$filemtime.'-'.$file] = [
             'pathname'=>$pathname,
             'mtime' => $filemtime
          ]; 
      }//end foreach $files

       ksort($res, SORT_NATURAL);
       $results[$dirname] = end($res);
  }//end foreach $dirs

  return $results;
} //end getMyFolders

//call it like this for one path
$results = getLatestFromFolders('dir1');
echo $results['dir1']['mtime'];
echo $results['dir1']['pathname'];

//call it like this for multiple paths
$results = getLatestFromFolders(['dir1','dir2']);
echo $results['dir1']['mtime'];
echo $results['dir2']['mtime'];

//call it like this to exclude file .htaccess or any other files 
//the ['.','..'] dosnt matter because of if(is_dir($pathname)) continue; //skip folders
$results = getLatestFromFolders(['dir1','dir2'], ['.htaccess']);
echo $results['dir1']['mtime'];
echo $results['dir2']['mtime'];
```

Untested, but it should work in theory.  I can't test it in a sanbox because of `scandir` being off in most of them.

So forgive any typos etc...

I just thought of using `preg_grep` or `function getLatestFromFolders($dirs, $regex = '/.+/'){ ... foreach(preg_grep($regex, scandir($dirname)) as $file)` to use a regex against the filenames.  Then you could do `getLatestFromFolders($dir, '/\.(jpg|png)$/')` etc and match the extensions but I will leave that for another day.

Thanks!

Comment: For the other directories, would I have to do 2 more foreach loops? And in the loop how would I echo the timestamp?

Comment: @ArtisticPhooenix Thanks for your help so far mate, closest I've got all week. The echo of the time stamp (echo filemtime($results[$dirname]);) is showing 'January 01 1970 01:00'

And I'm guessing for the second column I just use the same loop but change $dirname with $dirnameTwo?

Comment: The point is to not change anything in the code, but to change the inputs the code uses. That way the code is re-usable.  `(echo filemtime($results[$dirname]);) is showing 'January 01 1970 01:00'`  What is `$results[$dirname]` it should be the filename with the path.

Comment: if you use the last example the function `One last one is this:`  then you would do `$results = getLatestFromFolders($dirname);` and then `if(isset($results[$dirname])) echo $results[$dirname]['mtime'];`

Comment: I'll try now, thanks for your help mate, been stuck on this for a week or so lol

Comment: oh, sorry to hear that.

Comment: Me too lol, so I replaced the code with //all the above stuff wrapped in a function, under that section with the results, would I have to create a loop for those in each td for them to show?

Comment: `$results` is an array so you just loop over it with `foreach`.

Comment: I've just done that, but when doing a foreach for results then echo the $result in the img src it comes up as unknown

Comment: Also if I just echo $result in the foreach loop it shows Array;

Comment: I have all the files showing, but they are all in one <td> using the first thing you posted "//covers all 3 directories" I need each folder in a new <td>, any ideas?